# nw.js html5 application cache max size (node-webkit)

Tags: node-webkit, nw.js

I'm in the process of planning an offline music player with nw.js.

Im going to want to  cache GB's of data for offline use within nw.js. What's the max size of nj.js application cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html5 cache size is 5mb. For media data is better to use simple disk data storage.

Comment: Yes, why not? Just use node js module `fs` to work with files.